# Can I ask for beginner resources?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm looking for a book, website, or video series that will teach a novice how to correctly use a professional grade camera. Would that be on topic?

Comment: Found [this video course on Amazon Prime Video](https://www.amazon.com/gp/video/detail/B01IDT78FO). So far so good, and it's included in my Prime membership.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be off topic as it's more of a shopping question.  If you had beginner questions about using a professional camera, they would certainly be on topic, but resource questions tend to be poor fits unless they can be fairly tightly constrained, simply because it's difficult to answer well in this kind of context.

Comment: Thanks. As I suspected.